# ReviewBoard: symbol XML_SetHashSalt, version EXPAT_2_0_1_RH not defined in file libexpat.so.1 with link time reference

Tags: python, review-board

I'm running ReviewBoard 2.0.15 and on some reviews I'm getting the following error:

```
Django Version: 1.6.11
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
[u'django.contrib.admin',
 u'django.contrib.auth',
 u'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 u'django.contrib.sites',
 u'django.contrib.sessions',
 u'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 u'djblets',
 u'djblets.configforms',
 u'djblets.datagrid',
 u'djblets.extensions',
 u'djblets.feedview',
 u'djblets.gravatars',
 u'djblets.log',
 u'djblets.pipeline',
 u'djblets.siteconfig',
 u'djblets.util',
 u'djblets.webapi',
 u'haystack',
 u'pipeline',
 u'reviewboard',
 u'reviewboard.accounts',
 u'reviewboard.admin',
 u'reviewboard.attachments',
 u'reviewboard.changedescs',
 u'reviewboard.datagrids',
 u'reviewboard.diffviewer',
 u'reviewboard.extensions',
 u'reviewboard.hostingsvcs',
 u'reviewboard.notifications',
 u'reviewboard.reviews',
 u'reviewboard.reviews.ui',
 u'reviewboard.scmtools',
 u'reviewboard.site',
 u'reviewboard.ssh',
 u'reviewboard.webapi',
 u'django_evolution']
Installed Middleware:
[u'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
 u'reviewboard.admin.middleware.InitReviewBoardMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
 u'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 u'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 u'djblets.siteconfig.middleware.SettingsMiddleware',
 u'reviewboard.admin.middleware.LoadSettingsMiddleware',
 u'djblets.extensions.middleware.ExtensionsMiddleware',
 u'djblets.log.middleware.LoggingMiddleware',
 u'reviewboard.accounts.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
 u'reviewboard.admin.middleware.CheckUpdatesRequiredMiddleware',
 u'reviewboard.admin.middleware.X509AuthMiddleware',
 u'reviewboard.site.middleware.LocalSiteMiddleware',
 u'djblets.extensions.middleware.ExtensionsMiddlewareRunner',
 u'reviewboard.admin.middleware.ExtraExceptionInfoMiddleware']


Traceback:
File "/opt/local/revboard/python/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.11-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/local/revboard/python/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ReviewBoard-2.0.15-py2.6.egg/reviewboard/accounts/decorators.py" in _check
  23.             return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/local/revboard/python/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ReviewBoard-2.0.15-py2.6.egg/reviewboard/site/decorators.py" in _check
  35.         return view_func(request, local_site=local_site, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/local/revboard/python/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ReviewBoard-2.0.15-py2.6.egg/reviewboard/reviews/views.py" in review_detail
  665.                         changedesc.fields_changed[field_id])
File "/opt/local/revboard/python/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ReviewBoard-2.0.15-py2.6.egg/reviewboard/reviews/fields.py" in get_change_entry_sections_html
  200.             'rendered_html': mark_safe(self.render_change_entry_html(info)),
File "/opt/local/revboard/python/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ReviewBoard-2.0.15-py2.6.egg/reviewboard/reviews/fields.py" in render_change_entry_html
  590.         old_lines = list(iter_markdown_lines(old_value))
File "/opt/local/revboard/python/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ReviewBoard-2.0.15-py2.6.egg/reviewboard/reviews/markdown_utils.py" in iter_markdown_lines
  212.     nodes = get_markdown_element_tree(markdown_html)
File "/opt/local/revboard/python/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ReviewBoard-2.0.15-py2.6.egg/reviewboard/reviews/markdown_utils.py" in get_markdown_element_tree
  274.     doc = parseString(b'<html>%s</html>' % markdown_html)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/dom/minidom.py" in parseString
  1927.         from xml.dom import expatbuilder
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py" in <module>
  32. from xml.parsers import expat
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/parsers/expat.py" in <module>
  4. from pyexpat import *

Exception Type: ImportError at /reviews/r/24291/
Exception Value: /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so: symbol XML_SetHashSalt, version EXPAT_2_0_1_RH not defined in file libexpat.so.1 with link time reference
```

If I run python using the same virtual environment manually, it works fine:

```
bin]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 01:49:05) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyexpat import *
>>>
```

I have verified that apache and python do use the exact same version of expat, so that can't be the problem either. I'm really confused as to why this would happen on only a handful of reviews out of several 100.

EDIT: I ran some more tests and I noticed some stuff.

I did notice one thing. The libexpat.so that apache is using points to /usr/local/lib/libexpat.so, and if I run the following on that file I get no results:

```
(virtualenv)[user@rbdev301 lib]$ strings libexpat.so.1.5.2 | grep XML_SetHashSalt
(virtualenv)[user@rbdev301 lib]$ strings libexpat.so.1.5.2 | grep EXPAT_2_0_1_RH
```

However, when I check which expat Python is using, I get this:

```
(virtualenv)[user@rbdev301 lib-dynload]$ ldd pyexpat.so 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff252a000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f52afbae000)
libpython2.6.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (0x00007f52af802000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f52af5e4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f52af250000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f52af04c000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f52aee48000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f52aebc4000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f52affe3000)
```

So, python is using the one in /lib64. If I run the same commands on that one, I do get results.

```
(virtualenv)[user@rbdev301 lib64]$ strings libexpat.so.1.5.2 | grep XML_SetHashSalt
XML_SetHashSalt
(virtualenv)[user@rbdev301 lib64]$ strings libexpat.so.1.5.2 | grep EXPAT_2_0_1_RH
EXPAT_2_0_1_RH
```

The one that Apache is using was compiled from the same source as the one that python is using, and they're both the same version. It just seems that Python is using the 64bit one and Apache is not? Maybe I'm on a wild goose chase here.

Comment: after the code snippet you inserted above simply print in the python console:  >>>  `pyexpat`  and send me the answer

Comment: I just get: NameError: name 'pyexpat' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this. I'm not sure if this is the "right" way, but it worked for me. Since I noticed that the libexpat.so.0 symlink in my apache lib dir was pointed at the one in /usr/local/lib and that one did in fact not contain the strings that the error was complaining about, I deleted that symlink and created a new one that pointed at /lib64/libexpat.so.1.5.2, like so:

```
sudo ln -s /lib64/libexpat.so.1.5.2 libexpat.so.0
```

Then I restarted the machine and everything works as expected.

Just thought I'd post what solved it for me in case anyone else runs into this weird error.